# Listening to raised event in .NET Core Web API service

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I will keep it simple. I have two services in my ASP.NET Core WebAPI project.
ServiceA and ServiceB.

Service A is responsible for sending emails when Service B raises an event. Service B has an event handler and a delegate and the event is raised correctly. However, the problem is in Service A when trying to handle the event via `+= EventHandlingMethod()`;

The handler method `EventHandlingMethod()` is never called. I have placed a breakpoint inside the method but it never triggers, event after method `EventRaised()` has been called from `Service B` correctly.

Is it possible because Service A is set up in Startup.cs as `services.AddTransient<IServiceA, ServiceA>();`?

Comment: No, if you will do with the same object.

Comment: @DeepakMishra What do you exactly mean?

Comment: I mean if you will use the same object for registering and calling the event, then it will work with transient for example in the constructor of ServiceB you have IServiceA serviceA. If you use this same object (serviceA) for both registering and calling within the same object of serviceB. If it is possible can you share your code.

Comment: I am trying to de-couple the services, so is there a way to do this without injecting Service A in the constructor of Service B?

Comment: Use publish subscribe pattern.  Create a class C which has publish and subscribe methods and dictionary of <publisherid, List<Subscibers>>

Comment: @DeepakMishra Appreciate providing a sample

Comment: ok will do that tomorrow.

Comment: hope the solution works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have provided a simple example of publish-subscribe pattern. This is synchronous but if you are looking for an asynchronous version you can use [channels](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels) or any other message broker such as RabbitMQ / NServiceBus etc.

```
public class PublishSubscribeMiddleMan: IPubSub
{
    Dictionary<Type, List<ISubscriber>> pubSub = new Dictionary<Type, List<ISubscriber>>();

    public void PublishEvent<Publisher>(Publisher publisher)
    {
        Type t = publisher.GetType();
        if (pubSub.TryGetValue(t, out var subscribers))
        {
            subscribers.ForEach(subscriber => subscriber.EventHandlingMethod()); 
        }
    }

    public void Subscribe<Publisher>(ISubscriber subscriber)
    {
        Type t = typeof(Publisher);
        if (pubSub.TryGetValue(t, out var subscribers))
        {
            subscribers.Add(subscriber);
        }
        else pubSub.Add(t, new List<ISubscriber> { subscriber });
    }
}

public interface ISubscriber
{
    void EventHandlingMethod();
}


public interface IPubSub
{        
    void Subscribe<Publisher>(ISubscriber subscriber);
    void PublishEvent<Publisher>(Publisher publisher);
}

public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private readonly IPubSub publishSubscribe;

    public ServiceA(IPubSub publishSubscribe)
    {
        this.publishSubscribe = publishSubscribe;
    }
    public void RaiseEvent()
    {
        publishSubscribe.PublishEvent(this);
    }
}

public interface IServiceA
{
    void RaiseEvent();
}

public class ServiceB : ISubscriber
{
    public ServiceB(IPubSub publishSubscribe)
    {
        publishSubscribe.Subscribe<ServiceA>(this);
    }
    public void EventHandlingMethod()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You would need to register the PubSub inside ConfigureServices as shown:

```
services.AddScoped<IPubSub, PublishSubscribeMiddleMan>();
services.AddTransient<IServiceA, ServiceA>();
```

Comment: IPubSub must be a singleton, isn't it? Also, IObservable and IObserver are already a part of .Net core for a while, so no need to create them manually.